# How to check name of property in KeySelector?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

How to check of property in `KeySelector`?

I have function to sort collection by chosen column name:

```
private void DoListSort<T,TKey>(SortableObservableCollection<T> listBoxItems, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    listBoxItems.Sort(keySelector,ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

I would like to have:

```
private void DoListSort<T,TKey>(SortableObservableCollection<T> listBoxItems, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if ( keySelector.PropertyIAmAskingFor == ActualOrderByColumnName )
        listBoxItems.Sort(keySelector, ListSortDirection.Descending);
    else
        listBoxItems.Sort(keySelector,ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

Comment: How can `keySelector` have such property? Can you give an example of how you would call `DoListSort` and what would you pass for `keySelector`?

Comment: example: DoListSort<TruckDTO, string>(TruckItems, c => c.Truck). I want to know that list is sorted by Truck property.

Comment: Usually it is (x,y) => x.CompareTo(y).....

Comment: You can pass an `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` instead of `Func<T, TKey>` and that allows you to parse the expression and get the property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a `Func` as a compiled method. Even if this `Func` was created via a lambda expression, you cannot access such expression.

Instead, you can pass an `Expression` (which is like code as data) and parse it to get the property name like this:

```
private void DoListSort<T,TKey>(
    SortableObservableCollection<T> listBoxItems,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelectorExpression)
{
    MemberExpression member_expression =
        (MemberExpression)keySelector.Body;

    //This is the name of the property
    var property_name = member_expression.Member.Name;

    Func<T, TKey> keySelector = keySelectorExpression.Compile();

    //Continue here
    //...
}
```

Please note that this method would throw an exception if the passed expression is not a simple member access expression.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

`keySelector` is a function that returns type of `T` and gets as paramater Type of `TKey` so it doesn't have any property.